How to dynamically add routes in Angular micro frontend architecture during runtime?
I'm developing a micro frontend application using Angular 16, where different parts of the application are developed and deployed independently as micro frontends. Currently, I'm facing a challenge regarding the routing mechanism. I want to make the routes of my application dynamic so that whenever a new micro frontend is added in the future, its routes can be integrated without requiring a rebuild of the shell application.
Currently, I have a static route configuration in my shell application's routing module where each micro frontend's routes are defined. However, this approach requires manual modification and rebuilding of the shell application whenever a new micro frontend is added.
I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or examples on how to implement dynamic route loading in an Angular.
Thank you in advance for your help!

If you don't want to change the code, the routes must be passed as configuration.
